# XML DTD validation: character not allowed in declaration subset

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

Despite the presence of a root element and having inserted all the attribute in the ATTLIST of the DTD, I am incurring in several errors on the w3 validator:

> Error Line 17, Column 9: character "g" not allowed in declaration
>   subset `gender CDATA #REQUIRED>`
>
> Error Line 21, Column 45: there is no attribute "gender"
>    …    `<person user="WhozYourDaddy" gender="male" email="whozyourdaddy@gmail.com">`
>
> Error Line 21, Column 58: there is no attribute "email" …    `<person
>   user="WhozYourDaddy" gender="male" email="whozyourdaddy@gmail.com">`
>
> Error Line 29, Column 22: document type does not allow element
>   "lastdownload" here
>           `<lastdownload> PokemonGo </lastdownload>`
>
> Error Line 30, Column 19: document type does not allow element
>   "lastlogin" here
>           `<lastlogin> 12.03.2016 </lastlogin>`

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog [
<!ELEMENT catalog (person+)>
<!ELEMENT person (firstname,lastname,telephone,city,address, preferences, newsletter, downloads)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telephone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT preferences (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT newsletter (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastdownload (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastlogin (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT downloads (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST person 
        user CDATA #REQUIRED>
        gender CDATA #REQUIRED>
        email CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<catalog>
        <person user="WhozYourDaddy" gender="male" email="whozyourdaddy@gmail.com">
        <firstname> X </firstname>
        <lastname> XXXX </lastname>
        <telephone> 06666666 </telephone>
        <city> ZZZZZ </city>
        <address> Azxxxxxh xxx </address>
        <preferences> Educational </preferences>
        <newsletter> Yes </newsletter>
        <lastdownload> PokemonGo </lastdownload>
        <lastlogin> 12.03.2016 </lastlogin>
        <downloads> 5 </downloads>
    </person>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are severals errors to fix:

1. Remove the extra `>` characters in the `ATTLIST`.
2. add `lastdownload` and `lastlogin` to the content model of `catalog`.

Here is your XML with all fixes applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog [
<!ELEMENT catalog (person+)>
<!ELEMENT person (firstname,lastname,telephone,city,address, preferences, 
                  newsletter, lastdownload, lastlogin, downloads)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telephone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT preferences (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT newsletter (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastdownload (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastlogin (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT downloads (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST person 
        user CDATA #REQUIRED
        gender CDATA #REQUIRED
        email CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<catalog>
  <person user="WhozYourDaddy" gender="male" email="whozyourdaddy@gmail.com">
    <firstname> X </firstname>
    <lastname> XXXX </lastname>
    <telephone> 06666666 </telephone>
    <city> ZZZZZ </city>
    <address> Azxxxxxh xxx </address>
    <preferences> Educational </preferences>
    <newsletter> Yes </newsletter>
    <lastdownload> PokemonGo </lastdownload>
    <lastlogin> 12.03.2016 </lastlogin>
    <downloads> 5 </downloads>
  </person>
</catalog>
```